# Show partial view on button click

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

Class in Models:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace CalcFactory.Models
{
public partial class TableDetails
{
    public String Dates { get; set; }
    public double InvoiceAmount { get; set; }
    public String InterestRate { get; set; }
    public double InterestAmount { get; set; }
    public double Amortization { get; set; }
    public double CapitalBalance { get; set; }
}

public partial class TableDetails
{
    public List<TableDetails> Tables { get; set; }
}
}
```

Home Controller:

```
public ActionResult CreateCalculation()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult TableDetails()
    {
        return PartialView("TableDetail");
    }
```

My partial view (TableDetails):

```
@model IEnumerable<CalcFactory.Models.TableDetails >
@using CalcFactory.Models
@if (Model != null)
    {
        <div class="grid">
            <table cellspacing="0" width="80%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Dates
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Invoice amount
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Interest rate
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Interest amount
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Amortization
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Capital balance
                        </th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left">
                                @item.Dates
                            </td>
                            <td align="left">
                                @item.InvoiceAmount
                            </td>
                            <td align="left">
                                @item.InterestRate
                            </td>
                            <td align="left">
                                @item.InterestAmount
                            </td>
                            <td align="left">
                                @item.Amortization
                            </td>
                            <td align="left">
                                @item.CapitalBalance
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>

    }
```

And where I want the partial view to show:

```
<input type="submit" id="anCalcBtn" class="calcBtn" name="anSubmitBtn" value="Calculate" title="Calculate your calculation"></input>
<div class="calcDetail" id="anCalcDetail">
                    @model CalcFactory.Models.TableDetails
                        @{Html.Partial("TableDetail");}
                    </div>
```

My JS:

```
$('#anCalcBtn').click(function () {
$('#anCalcDetail').load('/Home/TableDetails/');
```

});

Why doesn't this work for me? I have this partial view that I want to show on the submit click. I'm not sure if I'm doing right with the Controller, but this partial view is suppose to show in the CreateCalculation page.

Comment: You are using `type="submit"` it must be submitting the form. try with `type="button"`

Comment: Tried with button as well. Doesnt work =/

Comment: I have added an alertbox in the beginning of JS and it doesn't show

Comment: Try with `$(document).on('click', '#anCalcBtn', function () {` instead of `$('#anCalcBtn').click(function () {`

Comment: Satpal: I've changed that and now the functions is executed because the alertbox is showing, but the partialview is not showing

Comment: please take a look at the load function documentation here https://api.jquery.com/load/, it says that load only replace the content of the matched element only "When a successful response is detected (i.e. when textStatus is "success" or "notmodified")". have you checked if the debugger hits the action on the server when you click on the button by debugging the application?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and the breakpoint does hit the TableDetails action.
The problem is that no model is sent to the TableDetail view and therefore no HTML is returned.
I've altered your TableDetail action and created a mock model:

```
public ActionResult CreateCalculation()
{
    return View("Index");
}
public ActionResult TableDetails()
{
    List<TableDetails> tdList = new List<TableDetails>();
    TableDetails td = new TableDetails();
    td.Dates = "Dates";
    td.InterestAmount = 10;
    td.InvoiceAmount = 5;
    tdList.Add(td);
    return PartialView("TableDetail", tdList);
}
```

This code returns a table with one row below the Calculate button